# Costmap wagon ruts Layer

Tags: ros, navigation, path, costmap

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I m trying to make some preference highways path.
So in order to the robot go from point a to point b, the cost map will be such that the robot will consider walking to the nearst highway to walkout only next to the point b.

Reading about layered costmaps, i found one presentation from David V. Lu, Dave Hershberger, and William D. Smart, named "Layered Costmaps for Context-Sensitive Navigation" (http://wustl.probablydavid.com/publications/IROS2014.pdf). There it is explaned one layer named wagon ruts. I thougth that  i can use one implementation of this type and load on this layer preference paths where the cost is negative or it will be multiple the total cost by an small factor.

Someone has any idea if there something like this already developed?

Thanks,
Henrique

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244618/costmap-wagon-ruts-layer/) by [Henrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/28087/henrique/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2016-09-27

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The wagon ruts layer was never released, since if I recall correctly, it was for a beta version of layered costmaps.

The easiest way to implement it now would be a static layer with some added cost on the nonhighway cells. You cannot set a value in a costmap to a negative value, although you could (theoretically) make a layer that subtracted from whatever values were already in a previous layer.

---

Originally posted by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) with karma: 10932 on 2016-09-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Henrique](https://answers.ros.org/users/28087/henrique/) on 2016-09-29**:
what a pity... I will try to do it =D Thanks.